# Using DropDownList(For) with model binding on nested class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I am relying heavily on EditorTemplates in my application, but I've run into a problem which I can not seem to solve, without not moving away from EditorTemplates for drop down lists.

Consider this (View)Model:

```
public class CreateStudentViewModel
{
    public DropDownList StudentTypes { get; set; }
    public CreateStudent Command { get; set; }
}

public class DropDownList {
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CreateStudent {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StudentTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

I use this to provide a way for the frontend user to set the student type, this is done with the following EditorTemplate:

```
@model DropDownList
<div class="form-group@(Html.ValidationErrorFor(m => m.SelectedValue, " has-error"))">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model.Items)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedValue, null)
</div>
```

And used within my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StudentTypes)
```

Now this EditorTemplate is binding to the `StudentTypes.SelectedValue` on `DropDownList`, which is good in some cases - but I need to bind this to my `Model.Command.StudentTypeId` here.

I know I can move all this code directly to the view and directly bind it, instead of having it inside a EditorTemplate, but I will try my best to avoid this.

Ideally I am thinking of extending the EditorFor to provide a way like:

`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StudentTypes, new { selectedValue = Model.Command.StudentTypeId });`

But I can not seem to translate this to something like:

`@Html.DropDownList(@ViewBag.selectedValue.ToString(), Model.Items);`

As this just places the value (int) as the field name. Any suggestions is welcome! :-)

Comment: In my experience, the html.dropdownlist in razor has always been picky. I've found myself too often having to smush everything into a convoluted viewmodel to get it to bind the way that I need it to, especially with complex entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chief problem here is encapsulating your drop down list in a class in order to rely on the C# type editor template convention. Instead, just use your model directly and use `UIHint` to tell Razor to use a particular template. Here's a simplified version of what I use:

**View Model**

```
[UIHint("Choice")]
public int SelectedFoo { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FooChoices { get; set; }
```

**Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Choice.cshtml**

```
@{
    var choices = ViewData["choices"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ?? new List<SelectListItem>();

    if (typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType) && ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType != typeof(string))
    {
        @Html.ListBox("", choices)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("", choices)
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedFoo, new { choices = Model.FooChoices })
```

In case it's not obvious, the conditional in the editor template determines if the property is a value or list type, and either uses a drop down list control or listbox control, respectively.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this out. Instead of using the UIHint annotation, i can just point directly to the template using a string on EditorFor?

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me :-) Why are you suggesting ListBox and DropDownList? (just for info)

Comment: So there's one template to cover both scenarios. I don't want to have to care whether I'm expecting a single selected value or multiple selected values. I just feed the property to the template and if it needs a multi-select, it gets one.